# Can you use `std::remove_if` on a container of `std::unique_ptr`?

Tags: c++, c++11

Given an `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeType> >`, is it legal to use
`remove_if` on it?  In other words, given this code:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeType> > v;
//  fill v, all entries point to a valid instance of SomeType...
v.erase( std::remove_if( v.begin(), v.end(), someCondition ), v.end() );
```

, am I guaranteed after the erase that all pointers still in `v` are
valid.  I know that given the intuitive implementation of
`std::remove_if`, and given all of the implementations I've looked at,
they will be.  I'd like to know if there is anything in the standard
which guarantees it; i.e. that `std::remove_if` is not allowed to copy
any of the valid entries without recopying the copy into its final
location.

(I am, of course, supposing that the condition doesn't copy.  If the
condition has a signature like:

```
struct Condition
{
    bool operator()( std::unique_ptr<SomeType> ptr ) const;
};
```

, then of course, all of the pointers will be invalid after
`remove_if`.)

Comment: James Kanze asking questions - a very rare phenomenon!

Comment: `unique_ptr` is not copy constructible, so if you used that predicate your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Why not? `std::unique` is not copyable but movable. It can be moved to  the end of container.

Comment: @interjay: Move-assignable is enough to use `std::remove_if`.

Comment: @KennyTM: But the predicate given in the question takes a parameter by value, so needs a copy constructor.

Comment: @KennyTM: Passing a `std::unique_ptr` as value would remove the raw pointer, leaving it `nullptr`.

Comment: @interjay He said that his predicate doesn't copy.

Comment: @VJovic: No, he didn't. He gave that predicate as an example of one that *does* copy. Then he made an incorrect statement about pointers being invalidated, which would be true with `auto_ptr` but not `unique_ptr` (the code simply wouldn't compile).

Comment: @interjay Ok, that is right. Copying `unique_ptr` is causing compilation errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

25.3.8 in the N3290 speaks about remove function :

> Requires: The type of *first shall satisfy the MoveAssignable
>   requirements (Table 22).

and

> Note: each element in the range [ret,last), where ret is the returned
>   value, has a valid but unspeciﬁed state, because the algorithms can
>   eliminate elements by swapping with or moving from elements that were
>   originally in that range.

This means that it depends on your predicate operator. Since your predicate doesn't create a copy, then the elements are not going to be copied.

Comment: §25.3.8/1 is a constraint on the targetted type, not on the 
implementation of `remove`.  §25.3.8/6 is what I was looking for.  Too 
bad it's a note, and not normative.  But it does make the intent clear.
I should have read the notes, and not just the normative text, before
posting.  +1 anyway, and I'll consider it the final response if no one
finds anything more definite.

Comment: I've got n3242. Is §25.3.8/6 added after that? My /6 discusses about `remove_copy[_if]`.

Comment: I believe that note is incorrect.  Good thing it isn't normative. ;-)  The algorithm is not allowed to swap elements because the elements aren't required to be Swappable.  The algorithm can only use move assignment.

Answer (score 8):

Just like `erase()` and `resize()`, `remove_if()` will *move* elements (possibly via swapping), so the container elements do not need to be copyable. There's nothing special about `unique_ptr`, it's just another move-only type.

As you point out, the predicate should of course take elements by const-reference. Again, just like for any movable type.

Comment: Where is this stated in the standard?  And more importantly, where is it 
stated that `remove_if` doesn't move to some temporary, perhaps later to
leave the value there because it determines that doesn't need to put it
elsewhere?  The containers and there member functions have been reworded
to reflect move semantics, but I'm not aware of any changes in the
language describing `remove_if` in this regard.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Note that the state of the "removed" elements is unspecified. Your pointers will be released at the latest when you erase the tail sequence or when you reassign the elements in it, but possibly sooner (i.e. the standard doesn't say).

Comment: @KerrekSB The state of the "removed" elements isn't what is worrying me.  It's the state of the elements which weren't removed.  Suppose `remove_if` takes a copy of the element preparatory to moving it, then decides that it doesn't have to be moved.

Comment: @JamesKanze: It wouldn't do that. It would only ever *move* the elements. If you don't have a copy constructor and the move constructor isn't `noexcept`, then it wouldn't even compile, I think, or at least then you have to live the the risk of having exceptions. (This follows from 17.6.3.5: Allocator Requirements.)