# How to use remove_if on an std::vector of std::unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, stl, unique-ptr

I'm trying to `remove_if` a vector of `unique_ptr`. Having forgotten to have my lambda not attempt to copy parameters, I searched for the explanation and found it in [Can you use `std::remove_if` on a container of `std::unique_ptr`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415016/can-you-use-stdremove-if-on-a-container-of-stdunique-ptr).

But when I attempt to pass my lambda parameter by reference or const ref as advised there and in other questions on the matter, I still get `'std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<int,std::default_delete<int>> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function`. I don't get why this copy construct would be called.

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v {
    std::make_unique<int>(1),
    std::make_unique<int>(2),
    std::make_unique<int>(3)
};

auto result = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::unique_ptr<int> &it) {return *it > 2; });
```

What am I missing ?

Comment: Issue is vector initialization... you cannot use initializer_list here :/

Answer (score 3):

> What am I missing ?

It's complaining about the construction, not the use.

`std::initialiser_list` can only be copied from, so `std::initialiser_list<std::unique_ptr<...>>` is useless.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v;
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));    
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));    
    v.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(3));    
    
    auto result = std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [](const std::unique_ptr<int> &it) {return *it > 2; });
    v.erase(result, v.end());
}
```

[See it on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/00251f733175e31f)

Comment: Whoops. Thanks !

Comment: Relevant quote: `The underlying array is a temporary array of type const T[N], in which each element is copy-initialized (except that narrowing conversions are invalid) from the corresponding element of the original initializer list.`